# Estimation of log-likelihood via importance sampling

Tags: likelihood, importance-sampling, variational-bayes

I am looking at a model trained with [stochastic gradient variational Bayes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114). In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4082) an importance sampler is proposed to estimate the likelihood:

$$p(x) \approx {1 \over S} \sum_{s=1}^S {p(x|z_s) p(z_s) \over q(z_s|x)}$$

with $h_s \sim q(z_s|x)$.

It is not entirely necessary what the quantities mean in order to understand the question, but I will give some info. We are looking at a graphical model of the form $z \rightarrow x$, with $z$ being continuous. The map from $z$ to $x$ is a nonlinear regressor representing a conditional distribution $p(x|z)$. $p(z)$ on the other hand is just a prior. $q(z|x)$ is a "recognition model", which approximates the intractable $p(z|x)$ with another nonlinear regressor. Consider that these distributions are given and fixed, their estimation is a different matter--it is a variational method which also gives us an upper bound on the negative log-likelihood.

Now, it seems I have reproduced the results on their models and one data set. Yet, I have two practical questions.

1) How to test an importance sampler? Since $p(x)$ is intractable, I guess it can only be done for small models. The route I went is to assert its correctness on factor analysis, where $p(x)$ is tractable and I made up a very simple $q(x|h)$.

2) The other question is that I am ultimately interested in the negative log-likelihood for comparative reasons. Thus I arrived at
$$-\log p(x) = \log S - \log (\sum_{s=1}^S \exp(\log p(x|z_s) + \log p(z_s) - \log q(z_s|x)).$$

A nice side effect is that this quantity can be computed numerically stable with the log-sum-exp trick.

However, depending on the sample size $S$, I get the following results for my negative log likelihood:

```
1     -> 29.6682416864
20    -> 22.144055709761528
50    -> 21.067476078084795
100   -> 20.458267754505115
200   -> 19.901382220921288
1000  -> 18.911037074948325
10000 -> 17.8730836533
```

[image: Results of importance sample given sample size.]

I do not understand this asymptotic behaviour. Does it make sense? Or is sth wrong in the deviation of the log-likelihood sampling.

Furthermore, I have an upper bound on that value, which is ~14. Thus, if everything is correct this should converge to a value lower than that.

Comment: 2) a potential reason for this divergent behaviour is an infinite variance of the importance sampling estimator. 1) I do not understand the meaning of "test", except in the above meaning of finite vs. infinite variance. You could e.g. check that the average of the importance weights converges to one.